# AngularJS ng-class multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to apply a specific class to an li element if 2 conditions are true, so I wrote the following code but it is not seem to be working

```
ng-class="{current:isActive('/'), loginStatus: false}"
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it so that the class is applied only if route is at / and loginstatus is false? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key should define the class you want, and the rest should be the expression to evaluate, which determines if the class is shown...

```
ng-class="{current:isActive('/') && loginStatus === false}"
```

What you were saying was more like... set class `current` if `isActive('/')` and also set class `loginStatus` if `false` is true.

Comment: I'd recommend === instead of ==

Comment: I think I remember that `===` became fashionable around the same time as the Gillette Mach III. Now there are razors with four blades, do you think javascript needs an `ulta equality` comparison symbol - `====`?

Comment: @GonchuB - you are right of course - I changed it. But what about simply `&! loginStatus` - it is probably fine too no? Depends on what `loginStatus` can be.

Answer (score 2):

Right now it is set up to add the class `current` if `isActive('/')` return true, and the class `loginStatus` if `false` is `true` (which it, obviously, never will be).

What you need to do, to add the class `current` if `isActive('/')` AND `loginStatus == false`, is simply

```
ng-class="{current:isActive('/') && !loginStatus}"
```