# Adding multiple expressions using ng-class in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to set the class `.active` when the path is `http://localhost/#/` or `http://localhost/#/main/` as both paths are the same page.

Why does `ng-class="{'class1' : expression1, 'class1' : expression2}"` not work?

**Controller**

```
angular.module('testApp')
  .controller('NavmenuCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
  $scope.isActive = function (providedPath) {
    return providedPath === $location.path();
  };
});
```

**Partials View**

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/'), active: isActive('/main/')}">
  <a href="#/">Home</a>
</li>
```

Related links

[Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

[AngularJS ng-class multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887513/angularjs-ng-class-multiple-conditions)

[Oliver Tupman: Keep CSS classes out of your Angular controllers](https://coderwall.com/p/r3_geg)

[Scotch.io: the many ways to use ng-class](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

Comment: `ng-class="{ active: isActive('/') || isActive('/main/')}"` ? and did you check if `$location.path()` is what you expect?

Comment: Does it work for one path and not the other? You could also write it using the or operator for one instance of the class. { active: condition1 || condition2 }

Comment: Try inserting a `console.log("provided: " + providedPath + " location: " + $location.path());` into your isActive method.  You can then see in the console what is being compared to what, which can often point out problems.

Comment: It doesn't work because angular evaluates the argument as an object and in your example the property class1 is duplicated.

Comment: @fiskers7 Yes, my original code only worked for the second URL path.

Comment: @PSL Yes, `console.log($location.path());` returns the correct path.  You and fiskers7 both have the best answer. Who wants the credit? :)

Comment: let isActive take multiple arguments `isActive('/', '/main/')` and inside isActive do `return [].indexOf.call(arguments, location.path()) > -1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making my comment an answer, Yes your issue is with the duplicate keys, you could just do:-

```
ng-class="{ active: isActive('/') || isActive('/main/')}"
```

Or probably better:-

Let your `isActive` class accept multiple arguments:-

```
$scope.isActive = function () {
    //Look for a match in the arguments array
    return [].indexOf.call(arguments, location.path()) > -1;
};
```

and use it as:-

```
ng-class="{ active: isActive('/', '/main/')}"
```

[Shim support for `indexOf` for older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Have an upvote for getting your answer in before me!

Comment: @fiskers7 Can you put your comment as an answer so I can at least up vote it?

Answer (score 1):

Day late but hopefully worth something.

You could also write it using the or operator for one instance of the class.

`ng-class="{ 'active': condition1 || condition2 }"`